# Delete all characters in a string that are not alphabetic in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a string `a, banana` 
I want to remove the space and comma from the string.
My code:

```
for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
   if(!isalpha(*it)) s.erase(it);
```

But what I'm getting is `A banana`. 
If i just try with `A banana` then I get `Abanana`. I don't know why it doesn't remove the space when there is a comma before that?

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger. What happens to the string when you call `s.erase(it)`? Where does `it` point to then? What does `++it` do to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a job for [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(begin(s), end(s), [](char c)
{
    return !isalpha(c);
});

// remove_if returns the new end, we need to erase from that to the old end
// (see the "erase-remove" idiom, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase–remove_idiom)
s.erase(new_end, end(s));
```

---

The problem with your current code is that [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) modifies the string you're iterating over, and you simply skip (with `it++`) the next character in the string.

You need to use [the iterator returned by `erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase#Return_value) as the next iterator to check:

```
for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); /* empty */)
{
    if(!isalpha(*it))
        it = s.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General best practice for iterating through an array and removing elements from it: Iterate backwards

```
for(auto it = s.end() - 1; it >= s.begin(); it--)
    if(!isalpha(*it) || *it == ' ')
        s.erase(it);
```

Comment: [References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a `basic_­string` sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that `basic_­string` object: \[...\] Calling non-const member functions, except `operator[]`, `at`, `data`, `front`, `back`, `begin`, `rbegin`, `end`, and `rend`.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.require#4)